# How can I add a Report Wizard? c#

Tags: c#, wpf, report, wizard

How can I add a report wizard on my project if there is not that option on Add New Item menu?
[image]

I need to install something?

Comment: what type of reports are you wanting to create..? Crystal Reports..? what version of VS are you using..? can you also edit the question and explain what it is you are trying to do in regards to creating a report..? this could be `HTML, Excel, TextFile..etc..` please be more specific and read the link on [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the project template in [this video](https://youtu.be/WQcaBGIkZig?t=9) then you need to install SQL Server Data Tools.

The version you need depends on which version of Visual Studio you're using. As far as I [know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh500335(v=vs.103).aspx) it ships with VS2012-2015, so you have to modify your installation of VS and add this feature.

VS2015 changing installation:

[image: Change installation]

Adding feature to VS

[image: Adding feature]